# How to convert a rawdate to "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

Tags: python-3.x

the parameter is rawdatetime, consists of an abbreviated name of the day of the week, a three-character abbreviation of the name of the month, and a time zone abbreviation.  An example:
                "Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018"
I want to convert it to "2018-09-05 09:23:03" then return it, is there any method can solve it without built-in functions?

I tried use split() to make a list then adjust the index order to show them correctly.
Here's my codes

```py
def format_datetime(raw_datetime):

    time = raw_datetime.split()
    del time[0]
    del time[-2]
    f_time =  
    return f_time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(format_datetime("Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy

```py
print(datetime.strptime("Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018", '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y'))
```

Comment: it works but I want to know can "EDT" be used by %Z? I changed EDT to %Z and it dosent work.

Comment: from datetime import datetime

def format_datetime(raw_datetime):

    time = datetime.strptime(raw_datetime, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")

    return time
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(format_datetime("Wed Sep 5 9:23:03 EDT 2018"))

Comment: No, that's not possible. But knowing the conversion you are asking for, the timezone does not influence the result.